# Has there been any work done on fluid dynamic or acoustic modeling of the human oral (or nasal) cavity?

Tags: reference-request, ab-initio-calculations, statistical-thermodynamics, biomaterials, fluid-dynamics

The purpose is for me to develop a deeper understanding of speech production and how distinct features that identify a phenome are produced.

*ab initio* models based on classical & statistical mechanics are preferable.

Comment: Before downvoting it would be nice if the issue was pointed out: is the question not clear or does it belong in another network or is it a duplicate or something else. That helps with getting an answer. Simply downvoting with no other interaction makes these websites that much more useless.

Answer (score 3):

The paper bellow can give you some insides. Using a Computer Tomography recording, they build a 3D model for computer simulation using FEM (Finite Element Method) and then do a 3D printing.

The article:
T. Vampola, J. Horáček, V. Radolf, J. G. Švec, and A. Laukkanen, *Influence of nasal cavities on voice quality: Computer simulations and experiments*, J. Acoust. Soc. Am. **148** 3218-3231 (2020) DOI: [10.1121/10.0002487](https://doi.org/10.1121/10.0002487)

The abstract:

> Nasal cavities are known to introduce antiresonances (dips) in the
> sound spectrum reducing the acoustic power ofthe voice. In this study,
> a three-dimensional (3D) finite element (FE) model of the vocal tract
> (VT) of one femalesubject was created for vowels [a:] and [i:] without
> and with a detailed model of nasal cavities based on CT(Computer
> Tomography) images. The 3D FE models were then used for analyzing the
> resonances, antiresonancesand the acoustic pressure response spectra
> of the VT. The computed results were compared with the measurementsof
> a VT model for the vowel [a:], obtained from the FE model by 3D
> printing. The nasality affects mainly the lowestformant frequency and
> decreases its peak level. The results confirm the main effect of
> nasalization, i.e., that soundpressure level decreases in the
> frequency region of the formantsF1–F2and emphasizes the frequency
> region of theformantsF3–F5around the singer’s formant cluster.
> Additionally, many internal local resonances in the nasal andparanasal
> cavities were found in the 3D FE model. Their effect on the acoustic
> output was found to be minimal, butaccelerometer measurements on the
> walls of the 3D-printed model suggested they could contribute to
> structure vibra-tions.

Comment: Thanks. This is along the lines of what I am looking for

Comment: J Malinen has also worked on this problem for a long time, see e.g. https://asa.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1121/1.5095250

Comment: Yeah, came across J Malinen's work in 'related' sections.